# Reading event log remotely with Get-EventLog in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, powershell-cmdlet

I've a powershell script which runs on server(test-server) and reads the log file of his client(DC1).

- Both sides can ping to each other.
- On both sides, firewalls are disabled.
- Remote Desktop and Remote Assistance are enabled on DC1.

  ```
  Get-EventLog System -ComputerName test-server -Source Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon # WORKS
  Get-EventLog System -ComputerName DC1 -Source Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon # DOESN'T WORK
  ```

I run this script on test-server. As you see when I read the local log file on test-server it works fine but if I try to read the log file of DC1 remotely I get the error "*Get-EventLog : The network path was not found.*".

*Screenshot of the error:*
[image]

How can I avoid this error and read the log file of DC1 from test-server with using Get-EventLog?

Comment: Lack of permissions?Can you execute 'dir \\dc1\c$' from test server?

Comment: @Shay Levy I just tried it. I get the directory list, so I can.

Comment: can you list dc1 processes/services?

Comment: @Shay Levy It's getting strange. `Get-Service -ComputerName DC1` gave me a long list without any error, so this works too I assume.

Comment: What do you get for: Get-EventLog System -ComputerName DC1 ?

Comment: @Shay Levy, I've attached a screenshot of the error.

Comment: Is DC1 a Windows XP machine? http://tediousscripts.blogspot.nl/2009/01/powershell-geteventlog-on-windows-xp.html

Comment: Is the remote registry service enabled on DC1? http://paragonwindows.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/how-to-open-event-log-of-remote-computer-using-powershell/

Comment: @Lars Truijens , DC1 is Windows 7 Ultimate x64 SP1

Comment: @Lars Truijens, Yes that did the trick, it works now! I've set this service 'Automatic'. Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

@Lars Truijens's suggestion solved my issue. But other suggestions are also important to check.

So, here is the checklist if you get this kind of error when you try to get log files remotely:

- Disable or set firewall settings on both sides.
- Enable Remote Desktop and Remote Assistance on client machine.
- Can you ping to the client machine?
- Run `dir \\dc1\c$` to see that you are allowed to reach to the
  harddisk. (*@Shay Levy's suggestion*)
- Run `Get-Service -ComputerName YOURCOMPUTERNAME` to see that you are
  allowed to reach to the services. (*@Shay Levy's suggestion*)
- **Start the Remote Registry service.** (*@Lars Truijens's suggestion and
  this made it work for me*)

Here is the screenshot of this solution:
[image: SolutionScreenshot]

Comment: The firewall is perhaps necessary, but the remote registry was the key.
sc \\<computername> config remoteregistry start=demand
sc \\<computername> start remoteregistry 
Those two commands will get you going

Comment: For Powershell:
`Get-Service -Name RemoteRegistry -ComputerName <Srv1> | Set-Service -StartupType Automatic` (because it's probably disabled)
 and then `Get-Service -Name RemoteRegistry -ComputerName <Srv1> | Start-Service` to start it

Answer (score 11):

Starting the **RemoteRegistry** service did not help in my case.

Apparently, there is a difference between the remoting that is accessed via the ComputerName parameter in some cmdlets such as Get-Service and the newer form of remoting accessed with cmdlets such as Invoke-Command.

> Since traditional remote access is implemented by individual cmdlets,
> it is inconsistent (uses different techniques and demands different
> requirements) and available only in selected cmdlets. The technology
> used for remote access can vary from cmdlet to cmdlet and is not
> readily known to you. Each cmdlet uses whatever remoting technology
> its author chose. Most cmdlets use Remote Procedure Call (RPC), but
> might also require additional services and settings on the target
> system.
>
> Beginning in Windows PowerShell 2.0, there is an alternate and more
> universal way of accessing remote systems: Windows PowerShell
> Remoting. With this type of remoting, Windows PowerShell handles
> remote access for all commands. It transfers your commands to the
> remote system using the relatively new and highly configurable WinRM
> service, executes the code in a separate session that runs on the
> remote system, and returns the results to the calling system.
>
> http://powershell.com/cs/media/p/7257.aspx

When I swapped from this command

```
get-eventlog -LogName System -computername <ServerName>
```

to this

```
invoke-command {get-eventlog -LogName System} -ComputerName <ServerName>
```

I no longer got the following error

> get-eventlog : The network path was not found.

Comment: (oops: I downvoted this totally by mistake - and now my vote is locked - I was actually trying to upvote it) :-/

Comment: @monojohnny I edited the question - you should be able to change your vote now.

Comment: Invoke-Command is executed with WinRM while Get-Eventlog does not (I think maybe uses the Remote Registry service given the above answers?)