# Reading Event Log remotely with Get-EventLog in Powershell...across different Domains

Tags: powershell

Trying to use `Get-EventLog` cmdlet on a customer's server for my computer.

The server name is (for our purposes here) is `File01.customersdomain.local`, and the IP address is `192.168.0.100`.  We have this server NAT’d at our VPN with a NAT IP address of `10.99.10.100`, and also have this machine in our (seller’s) DNS as `File01.sellersdomain.local`.

Is there a trick to successfully using `Get-EventLog` cmdlet across different domains?  Granted, I could log into the machine via RDP and run it locally, but I would like to streamline the process a bit.

I’ve tried:

```
Get-EventLog  -Newest 5 -LogName "System" -ComputerName 10.99.10.5

Get-EventLog  -Newest 5 -LogName "System" -ComputerName File01.customersdomain.local

Get-EventLog  -Newest 5 -LogName "System" -ComputerName File01.sellersdomain.local

Get-EventLog  -Newest 5 -LogName "System" -ComputerName File01

Get-Credential CUSTOMERSDOMAIN\\(USER)

Get-EventLog  -Newest 5 -LogName "System" -ComputerName File01.sellersdomain.local
```

Each time I get the same message:

> The network path was not found.

`PING` and `Test-Connection` are successful.

*Note:  I’m not allowed to make any changes to the server without documented approval, nor am I allowed to make any recommendations that deviate from the customer's current security best practices.*

Comment: Is the port for remote event log monitoring open on the firewall?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790666/reading-event-log-remotely-with-get-eventlog-in-powershell

Comment: @BenH, TCP port 135 does appear to be blocked.

Comment: The suggestion of using `Invoke-Command` instead of RPC in the duplicate is a good one if PSRemoting is open. PSRemoting is so much better for Firewall traversal.